# Sublist to number

Tags: python, list, function

I'm working on the solution to a fun problem I found. The code I have gives a bunch of sublists, like (1, 2, 3, 0, 0). Is there a way to turn that sublist into the number 12300 and append it to a new list, `perm2`? I would have to do this for quite a few sublists, so preferably it would be a function I could run on the whole list (i.e., it'd iterate through the list, do the conversion for each number, and append each new number to the new list, though the old list would stay exactly the same).

So far, I have the code

```
import itertools
digits = [1,2,3,0,0]
perm = list(itertools.permutations(digits))
perm2 = []

print perm
def lst_var (lst):
    for i in lst:
        litem = lst[i]
        #conversion takes place
        perm2.append(v)

lst_var(perm)
```

But I really don't know how to do the conversion, and I can't find a solution anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: 12300 = 1 * 10000 + 2 * 1000 + 3 * 100 + 0 * 10 + 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function that creates an integer out of a list of numbers. The advantage of this function is that it does not convert the list of integers into a list of strings, which is a rather costly operation:

```
def list_to_int(ls):
    num = 0
    for digit in ls:
        num *= 10
        num += digit
    return num
```

Applied to your example:

```
list_to_int([1,2,3,0,0])
```

> 12300

In order to apply it to a list of sublists, you can either use a list comprehension or, as I would personally prefer, `map`:

```
sublists = [[7, 6, 6], [5, 7, 6], [9, 0, 9, 0], [8, 9, 5, 7, 8, 4]]
map(list_to_int, sublists)
```

> [766, 576, 9090, 895784]

So, following that model your code would end up looking something like:

```
digits = [1,2,3,0,0]
perm = map(list_to_int, itertools.permutations(digits))
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution!

Comment: If you do `num *= 10` before `num += digit` you can avoid dividing by 10

Comment: Thank you, @AndreaCorbellini. Just adopted your suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You here are a few different ways to solve this:

**1.** `perm2 = [int(''.join(str(i) for i in sublist)) for sublist in perm]`

**2.** `perm2 = [int(''.join(map(str, sublist))) for sublist in perm]`

A more **performant** mathematical version:

**3.** `print [reduce(lambda x, y: 10 * x + y, sublist) for sublist in perm]`

**4.** `print map(lambda x: reduce(lambda x, y: 10 * x + y, x), perm)`

This method converts the list to a string of this form -> Ex: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` first using `repr()` then slices to return a sublist.

**5.** `print [int(repr(sublist)[1::3]) for sublist in perm]`

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> import itertools
>>> digits = [1,2,3,0,0]
>>> perm = list(itertools.permutations(digits))
>>> perm2 = [int(''.join(map(str, sublist))) for sublist in perm]
>>> print perm2
[12300, 12300, 12030, 12003, 12030, 12003, 13200, 13200, 13020, 13002, 13020, 13002, 10230, 10203, 10320, 10302, 10023, 10032, 10230, 10203, 10320, 10302, 10023, 10032, 21300, 21300, 21030, 21003, 21030, 21003, 23100, 23100, 23010, 23001, 23010, 23001, 20130, 20103, 20310, 20301, 20013, 20031, 20130, 20103, 20310, 20301, 20013, 20031, 31200, 31200, 31020, 31002, 31020, 31002, 32100, 32100, 32010, 32001, 32010, 32001, 30120, 30102, 30210, 30201, 30012, 30021, 30120, 30102, 30210, 30201, 30012, 30021, 1230, 1203, 1320, 1302, 1023, 1032, 2130, 2103, 2310, 2301, 2013, 2031, 3120, 3102, 3210, 3201, 3012, 3021, 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321, 1230, 1203, 1320, 1302, 1023, 1032, 2130, 2103, 2310, 2301, 2013, 2031, 3120, 3102, 3210, 3201, 3012, 3021, 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]
```

**Some benchmarks:**

```
from timeit import timeit
repeat = 1000000
print 'Solution 1 took ->', timeit("import itertools;[int(''.join(str(i) for i in sublist)) for sublist in list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,0,0]))]", number=repeat), 'secs'
print 'Solution 2 took ->', timeit("import itertools;[int(''.join(map(str, sublist))) for sublist in list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,0,0]))]", number=repeat), 'secs'
print 'Solution 3 took ->', timeit("import itertools;map(lambda x: reduce(lambda x, y: 10 * x + y, x), list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,0,0])))", number=repeat), 'secs'
print 'Solution 4 took ->', timeit("import itertools;[reduce(lambda x, y: 10 * x + y, sublist) for sublist in list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,0,0]))]", number=repeat), 'secs'
print 'Solution 5 took ->', timeit("import itertools;[int(repr(sublist)[1::3]) for sublist in list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,0,0]))]", number=repeat), 'secs'
```

**Results (repeat = 1000000):**

```
Solution 1 took -> 242.802856922 secs
Solution 2 took -> 153.20646596 secs
Solution 3 took -> 97.4842221737 secs
Solution 4 took -> 87.8391051292 secs
Solution 5 took -> 122.897110224 secs
```

Comment: Thank you, this works beautifully, and it uses less code! I'll be accepting this.

Comment: Added a shorter comprehension also.

Comment: @heather Note that this is a couple of orders of magnitude slower than the mathematical method, if performance is a consideration. (Based on a quick run of both through timeit in python3.)

Comment: @glibdud, thank you, I'll consider that. At this point, performance isn't a consideration, but it could become one eventually.

Comment: I'll add to my answer using the less-pythonic, performant mathematical way in a bit.

Comment: @mrdomoboto, I just noticed something strange: using your code, some numbers that were in `perm` are not in `perm2`; I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: There's a very good reason for this, when you convert a string such as -> `00000` to an `int` literal, the result is `0`. If you want to keep leading zeros, remove the `int()` conversion at the end, note that you'll then have a list of strings.

Comment: @mrdomoboto, oh, no, I understand that. I mean that, for example, there are no numbers starting with 3 in `perm2`, but in `perm` there are sublists that start with 3.

Comment: Updated my answer with output.

Answer (score 0):

```
digits = [1,2,3,0,0]
int(''.join([str(x) for x in digits]))
```